# Ceiling / floor conversion formula

Tags: number-theory, arithmetic, ceiling-and-floor-functions

[Here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Floor_and_ceiling_functions) one can see the following formula:

[image]

for $m\ne 0$. However, if $m=1$ then we have $\lceil n\rceil = \lfloor n\rfloor$. So does this mean that Wikipedia is missing this condition that $m$ must be $\ge 2$?

Comment: $n$ is an integer, so this is fine.

Comment: But $\lceil n \rceil$ *does* equal $\lfloor n \rfloor$....

Comment: @fleablood  exactly.  That's what CheerfulParsnip and the answerer have already said.

Answer (score 2):

From the [start of the section](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Floor_and_ceiling_functions#Definition_and_properties):

> In the following formulas [...] **$k$, $m$, and $n$ are integers**

The formulas you derived for $m=1$ clearly hold for $n \in \Bbb Z$, so no problem arises.

Comment: You are correct, I assumed that $n$ is any real number $> 0$, in which case this does not hold.